# Solving a system of GCD equations with an unknown number of equations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve for $k$, given that $GCD(n - i, 2k - (2i - 1)) = 1$, for $i \in [0, k-1]$. How do I go about solving this system of GCD equations?

Comment: If $i=n$, then $2k-(2n-1)=\pm 1$.  Excluding these two cases, we may limit our search to $k\le n$.

Comment: The formulation is a bit unclear. Don't you want to solve $n$ for some arbitrary number of $k$ equations of the type above?

Comment: I want to solve for the smallest $k$, such that the system of equations is solved. $n$ is a known, $k$ is the unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $k$ satisfies the constraints, then we have
$$
GCD(n-i,2k-2i+1)=1~\text{for}~\forall i \in \{0,1,\dots,k-1\}
$$
Since $2k-2i+1$ is odd we can multiply the first argument with 2 to obtain the equivalent set of equations.
$$
GCD(2n-2i,2k-2i+1)=1~\text{for}~\forall i \in \{0,1,\dots,k-1\}
$$
The GCD is also not affected by adding/subtraction multiples of one of the arguments, so the equations are also equivalent to:
$$
GCD(2n-2k+1,2k-2i+1)=1~\text{for}~\forall i \in \{0,1,\dots,k-1\}
$$
Noting that the second argument is always odd, this can be reduced to a single equation as
$$
GCD(2n-2k+1,(2k+1)!!)=1
$$
and even further by noting that we only need all the prime factors of the double factorial. So if we define a product over only the prime numbers $p_i$
$$
P_k = \prod_{3\leq p_i\leq (2k+1)} p_i
$$
we find that in order for $k$ to be an acceptable solution it only has to satisfy 
$$
GCD(2n-2k-1,P_k) = 1
$$
and each value of $k$ would have to be checked individually.

If we are only interested in the smallest possible value of $k$, we first observe that in order for $k=1$ to be a solution for given $n$, we need
$$
GCD(2n-3,3)=GCD(2n,3)=GCD(n,3)=1
$$
So for every value of $n$ that is not a multiple of 3, we find that the smallest $k$ would be $k=1$. So we are left with only the cases $n=3m$ for some integer $m$.

For concluding the answer we are going to use the method of induction on the following:

- $k$ is the smallest value to satisfy $GCD(2n-2k-1,P_k) = 1$ if $2k+1$ is prime and $GCD(n,P_k)=P_{k-1}$.

For $k=1$ this was already demonstrated ($P_0=1$), so we assume that it has been shown for all $k<s$. Note that it also implies that the only values of $n$ that have no solution $k<s$ are multiples of $P_{s-1}$.

For $k=s$ to be the smallest solution for a given $n= m P_{s-1}$ we need
$$
GCD(2n-2s-1,P_s) = 1
$$
For $2s+1$ not a prime we have $P_s=P_{s-1}$ and
$$
GCD(2 m P_{s-1} - (2 s+1),P_{s-1}) \neq 1
$$
and $k=s$ is not a solution. For $2s+1$ is a prime we need to have 
$$
GCD(2 m P_{s-1} - (2 s+1),(2 s+1) P_{s-1}) = 1
$$
which is satisfied whenever $m$ is not divisible by $2s+1$. Hence $k=s$ is the smallest solution when $P_{s-1}|n$ and $P_{s}\not|n$.

In summary, in order to determine the smallest possible $k$ for a given $n$ we compare $n$ with the sequence of $P_k$. This can be reformulated to the following solution:

Find the smallest odd prime $p$ that does not divide a given $n$, then the smallest $k$ satisfying the conditions is $k=(p-1)/2$.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I will implement this and let you know, how it goes.

Comment: I agree with the result: "So for every value of $n$ that is not a multiple of $3$, we find that the smallest $k$ would be $k=1$." But the problem is that this does not agree with the solution to the problem. The problem is: [Project Euler, Problem 443](https://projecteuler.net/problem=443). I solved it in an alternate way starting from 1 and going up to $10^{15}$. The system of equations I posted above show up when I was trying to solve the problem starting at $10^{15}$ and going backwards. I might have formulated the system of equations incorrectly. Thanks once again for solving this for me.

Comment: No problem, it was an unusual but fun type of question to consider.